# redirectint to localhost:8080 on codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to make a logout function on codeigniter 4, and I'm realizing there is different things from v3

```
public function logout(){
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        
        return redirect()->to("/");
    }
```

this is not redirecting me to my virtualhost / route its redirecting  to `localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to set your base url in `/Config/App.php`

```
/* public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/'; // <-- what is there now */
public $baseURL = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'; // <-- change to your url
```

Then you can reference it

```
return redirect()->to(site_url()); // or
return redirect()->to("/");
```

Comment: this way redirects to http://localhost:8080/index.php

Comment: @aa_cr - did this fix your issue? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

go to .env file and remove 8080 from "app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/ci/'"